# How to add scala language support for monaco editor

Tags: scala, autocomplete, editor, monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

I am using Monaco editor in my angular project. I have seen, there is no support for the Scala language in Monaco editor. Does any one knows how to add third party library for scala in monaco editor?

Comment: maybe this is what you're looking for https://scalameta.org/metals/docs/editors/vscode.html ?

Answer (score 0):

The Scala language is supported by the [monaco-ace-tokenizer](https://github.com/brijeshb42/monaco-ace-tokenizer) library.